# Busqueda lenta con laravel y datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

Hola estoy tratando de hacer esta consulta para un filtrado, el problema es que cuando la información es demasiado extensa la búsqueda se demora mucho en procesar y al final me da un error, si recargo la pagina desde el botón del navegador varias veces me logra traer la información pero no creo que sea bueno decirle al usuario que recargue la pagina para obtener el resultado, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que la consulta no se demore mucho y que no me lance el error, esta es mi consulta:

```
public function indexCaja(Request $request)
    {
        $this->loadDate();
        $desde = $request->desde ? $request->desde : date('Y-m-d ') . '00:00:00';
        $hasta = $request->hasta ? $request->hasta : date('Y-m-d ') . '23:59:59';
        $tracking = $request->tracking ? $request->tracking : "";
        $codigo = $request->codigo ? $request->codigo : "";
        $por = $request->por ? ($request->por > 0 ? $request->por : -1) : -1 ;
        $casillero = $request->casillero ? ($request->casillero == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        $gastos = $request->gastos ? ($request->gastos == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        // $cajaDestinatario = $request->cajaDestinatario ? ($request->cajaDestinatario == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        // $cajaLabel = $request->cajaLabel ? ($request->cajaLabel == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        $tipoPago = $request->tipoPago ? $request->tipoPago : '-1' ;

        $liquidaciones = [];
        $agentes = [];
        $agentes_fil = [];

        $vcosto = [];
        $vgasto = [];
        $votros = [];
        $vremes = [];

        $srtData = '';
        $srtSele = '';
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            
            $srtData .= (($por > 1) ? " AND LI.cobrado_por=$por " : '');
            // $srtData .= (($tipoPago != '-1') ? " AND LI.cobrado_por=$por " : '');
            switch ($tipoPago) {
                case 'E':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.efectivo>0 ";
                break;
                case 'C':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.cheque>0 ";
                break;
                case 'P':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.prepagado>0 ";
                break;
                case 'B':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bbol>0 ";
                break;
                case 'G':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bgua>0 ";
                break;
                case 'PI':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bpic>0 ";
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            $srtSele .= (($casillero == 'S') ? " (SELECT (SELECT (SELECT US.codigo FROM users US WHERE US.id=PA.user_id LIMIT 1) FROM paquetes PA WHERE PA.paq_id=ST.paq_id  LIMIT 1) FROM stocks ST WHERE ST.liquidacion_id=LI.id LIMIT 1 ) AS casillero, " : ' "" AS casillero, ');
$query = "
                SELECT 
                    (SELECT IFNULL(USA.name, '') FROM users USA WHERE USA.id = LI.agent_id LIMIT 1) as nomAgente,
                    (SELECT IFNULL(USC.name, '') FROM users USC WHERE USC.id = LI.cobrado_por LIMIT 1) as nomCobra,
                    (LI.efectivo + LI.cheque + LI.prepagado + LI.bbol + LI.bgua + LI.bpic) AS valRubros,
                    $srtSele
                    LI.id AS idLiquidacion,
                    LI.*,
                    (
                        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                            OE.nombres_d
                            ORDER BY OE.nombres_d SEPARATOR ' - '
                        )
                        FROM stocordliqs SL
                        LEFT JOIN ordenes_de_envios OE ON OE.id = SL.orden_id
                        WHERE SL.liquidacion_id = LI.id
                    ) AS destinatarios
                FROM liquidacions LI
                WHERE LI.historico BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta' $srtData
            ";

            $liquidaciones = DB::select($query);
            // dd($liquidaciones);
            if ($gastos == 'S') { 
                $vcosto = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'C')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $vgasto = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'G')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $votros = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'O')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $vremes = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'R')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
            }
        }

        $l_cobra = Liquidacion::whereNotNull('historico')
        ->groupBy('cobrado_por')
        ->pluck('cobrado_por');

        $l_agentes = Liquidacion::whereNotNull('historico')
        ->groupBy('agent_id')
        ->pluck('agent_id');

        $agentes = User::whereIn('id', $l_agentes)->orWhereIn('id', $l_cobra)->orderBy('name')->get();
        $agentes_fil = [];
        if($por == 1){
            $agentes_fil = User::whereIn('id', $l_agentes)->get();
        }elseif($por > 1){
            $agentes_fil = User::where('id', $por)->get();
        }

        return view('admin.indexCaja', compact('liquidaciones', 'desde', 'hasta', 'tracking', 'agentes', 'agentes_fil', 'por', 'casillero', 'gastos', 'codigo', 'vcosto', 'vgasto', 'votros', 'vremes', 'tipoPago'));
    }
Y no creo que sea las relaciones ya que al si cambio mi consulta y la dejo asi:
public function indexCaja(Request $request)
    {
        $this->loadDate();
        $desde = $request->desde ? $request->desde : date('Y-m-d ') . '00:00:00';
        $hasta = $request->hasta ? $request->hasta : date('Y-m-d ') . '23:59:59';
        $tracking = $request->tracking ? $request->tracking : "";
        $codigo = $request->codigo ? $request->codigo : "";
        $por = $request->por ? ($request->por > 0 ? $request->por : -1) : -1 ;
        $casillero = $request->casillero ? ($request->casillero == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        $gastos = $request->gastos ? ($request->gastos == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        // $cajaDestinatario = $request->cajaDestinatario ? ($request->cajaDestinatario == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        // $cajaLabel = $request->cajaLabel ? ($request->cajaLabel == 'S' ? 'S' : 'N') : 'N' ;
        $tipoPago = $request->tipoPago ? $request->tipoPago : '-1' ;

        $liquidaciones = [];
        $agentes = [];
        $agentes_fil = [];

        $vcosto = [];
        $vgasto = [];
        $votros = [];
        $vremes = [];

        $srtData = '';
        $srtSele = '';
        // $srtSeleV = '';
        // $srtSeleGuia = '';
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            
            $srtData .= (($por > 1) ? " AND LI.cobrado_por=$por " : '');
            // $srtData .= (($tipoPago != '-1') ? " AND LI.cobrado_por=$por " : '');
            switch ($tipoPago) {
                case 'E':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.efectivo>0 ";
                break;
                case 'C':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.cheque>0 ";
                break;
                case 'P':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.prepagado>0 ";
                break;
                case 'B':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bbol>0 ";
                break;
                case 'G':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bgua>0 ";
                break;
                case 'PI':
                    $srtData .= " AND LI.bpic>0 ";
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            $srtSele .= (($casillero == 'S') ? " (SELECT (SELECT (SELECT US.codigo FROM users US WHERE US.id=PA.user_id LIMIT 1) FROM paquetes PA WHERE PA.paq_id=ST.paq_id  LIMIT 1) FROM stocks ST WHERE ST.liquidacion_id=LI.id LIMIT 1 ) AS casillero, " : ' "" AS casillero, ');

$query = "
            SELECT 
                (SELECT IFNULL(USA.name,'') FROM users USA WHERE USA.id=LI.agent_id LIMIT 1) as nomAgente,
                (SELECT IFNULL(USC.name,'') FROM users USC WHERE USC.id=LI.cobrado_por LIMIT 1) as nomCobra,
                (LI.efectivo + LI.cheque + LI.prepagado + LI.bbol + LI.bgua + LI.bpic) AS valRubros,
                $srtSele
                LI.*
            FROM liquidacions LI WHERE LI.historico BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta' $srtData
            ";
$liquidaciones = DB::select($query);
            // dd($liquidaciones);
            if ($gastos == 'S') { 
                $vcosto = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'C')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $vgasto = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'G')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $votros = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'O')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
                $vremes = Registrocg::where('tipo', 'R')->whereBetween('fecha', [str_replace(' 00:00:00', '',$desde), str_replace(' 23:59:59', '',$hasta)])->get();
            }
        }

        $l_cobra = Liquidacion::whereNotNull('historico')
        ->groupBy('cobrado_por')
        ->pluck('cobrado_por');

        $l_agentes = Liquidacion::whereNotNull('historico')
        ->groupBy('agent_id')
        ->pluck('agent_id');

        $agentes = User::whereIn('id', $l_agentes)->orWhereIn('id', $l_cobra)->orderBy('name')->get();
        $agentes_fil = [];
        if($por == 1){
            $agentes_fil = User::whereIn('id', $l_agentes)->get();
        }elseif($por > 1){
            $agentes_fil = User::where('id', $por)->get();
        }

        return view('admin.indexCaja', compact('liquidaciones', 'desde', 'hasta', 'tracking', 'agentes', 'agentes_fil', 'por', 'casillero', 'gastos', 'codigo', 'vcosto', 'vgasto', 'votros', 'vremes', 'tipoPago'));
    }
```

Y este es parte de mi código de la vista que trae esa información

````
<table class="table table1 table-sm table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-dark text-white">
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Agente</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Cobrado</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Destinatario</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Peso</th>
                                {{-- <th> Label</th> --}}
                                <th>Retirado</th>

                                <th nowrap>Total Liq.</th>
                                
                                <th>Efectivo</th>
                                <th>Cheque</th>
                                <th>Prepagado</th>
                                <th>Bolivariano</th>
                                <th>Guayaquil</th>
                                <th>Pichincha</th>
                                
                                <th>Total $</th>
                                <th> -- </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody  class="table-light">

                            @foreach($liquidaciones as $liquidacion)
                            <tr>

                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->casillero. '000' . $liquidacion->id }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nomAgente }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nomCobra }} </td>
                                <td>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach(explode(' - ', $liquidacion->destinatarios) as $destinatario)
                                            <li>{{ $destinatario }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->peso}} </td>
                                {{-- <td> {{ $liquidacion->guia ?? ''}} </td> --}}
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nombre_retiro }} </td>
                                <td> {{ number_format( $liquidacion->total, 2) }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->efectivo }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->cheque }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->prepagado }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bbol }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bgua }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bpic }} </td>
                                <td> {{ number_format($liquidacion->valRubros, 2) }} </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-edit-admin" data-id="{{ $liquidacion->id }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/admin/printLiquidacion?id={{ $liquidacion->id }}"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="/admin/detalle?token={{ $liquidacion->token }}#detalles" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                </td>
                                @php
                                    $total              += $liquidacion->total;
                                    $efectivo           += $liquidacion->efectivo;
                                    $cheque             += $liquidacion->cheque;
                                    $prepagado          += $liquidacion->prepagado;
                                    $bbol               += $liquidacion->bbol;
                                    $bgua               += $liquidacion->bgua;
                                    $bpic               += $liquidacion->bpic;
                                    $totalcancelado     += $liquidacion->valRubros;    
                                @endphp
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vcosto as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Costo</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvcosto += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vgasto as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Gasto</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">-{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvgasto += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($votros as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Otros ingresos</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo += $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvotros += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vremes as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Remesas</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                     <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{--<td></td> --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">-{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvremes += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach

                            @php 
                                $totalcancelado += $totalvotros - $totalvcosto - $totalvgasto - $totalvremes
                            @endphp 
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -5 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>V. Costo</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -4 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>V. Gasto</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -3 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>V. Otros</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -2 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>V. Remesas</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -1 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($efectivo, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($cheque, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($prepagado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bbol, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bgua, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bpic, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalcancelado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 

                                <td> -- </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- <td></td> --}}
                                <td>{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($efectivo, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($cheque, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($prepagado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bbol, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bgua, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bpic, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalcancelado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
 <script>
        $('.table').DataTable({
            // "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }],
            "order": [
                [0, 'asc']
            ],
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            dom: 'Blfrtip', 
            bProcessing: true
        });
    </script>
```
Alguien me puede ayudar para poder solucionar este problema por cierto la pagina ya esta aloja en un servidor, de antemano gracias.
````

Answer (score 0):

Datatable es una librería muy potente y tiene más de una forma para trabajar con ella, la que estás usando actualmente es la de renderizar el contenido en el front y luego procesarlo con la librería. Lo que para efectos prácticos es poco óptimo cuando tienes muchos registros, ya que todos los datos son cargados en la memoria del navegador y si los equipo no tienen suficientes recursos, la página no se podrá mostrar.

La solución para eso es trabajar con datatable server side processing, para que la información que se muestre, solo sea la que se solicita al servidor. Esto requiere que modifiques como obtienes los datos actualmente y como renderizas esos datos en el front. Ya que deberás implementar lógica para manejar la paginación y los filtros.

Puedes revisar estos links para que profundices sobre el tema

[Documentación](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

[Ejemplo de uso](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, revisare la documentación.